# CSS Grid: Keep equal number of children in each line of grid that has odd number of children

Tags: css-grid

I have a grid made of 3 elements in one row. There is a minmax set, so in case the screen gets smaller the one element will go to the new line. What I want to do is to keep equal number of elements in each line, so if the last one of these three elements goes to the new line, leaving two elements above - I don't want it to show. Of course I want it back when all grids are in one column.

I have found a simple way of doing this by using media queries, however I've got a feeling this can be done better. I may reuse this code on another subpage, where wrapper can be different, so it will not work properly. It's important that all elements are equal in width.

This is my solution. Is there any better?
https://jsfiddle.net/tucado/u2mwo4sd/10/

```
<div class="grid">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin:0; padding:0;
}

.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-gap:50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));  
}

.grid>div {
  background:lightblue;
  max-width:250px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:450px) and (max-width:700px) {
  .grid>div:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

[image: removed alone element]

Comment: Check out CSS [Container Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries)

Comment: Is there a way of using srcset or similar solution for other elements that img?

Comment: I don't understand how that relates to the question, could you perhaps edit your question to add an attempt/idea